# How can I get the JSON from kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

From the Kibana dashboard I've gotten this JSON. I need to use the "message" (which is the result of my script) in my website, how can I do that?

NB: the script is the input of logstash, which is sent to elasticsearch, then visualized with Kibana and this code is from the JSON section in kibana.

```
  {
  "_index": "test",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "l-RRWncBMkK0B15vMizO",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "command": "sh -c /home/ubuntu/hello.sh",
    "host": "elk",
    "@version": "1",
    "message": "bin\nboot\ndev\netc\nhome\ninitrd.img\ninitrd.img.old\nlib\nlib64\nlost+found\nmedia\nmnt\nopt\nproc\nroot\nrun\nsbin\nsnap\nsrv\nsys\ntmp\nusr\nvar\nvmlinuz\nvmlinuz.old\n",
    "@timestamp": "2021-01-31T21:20:06.716Z"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-01-31T21:20:06.716Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1612128006716
  ]
}
```

Comment: which code ? the request Elasticsearch or the filter Logstash ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be incomplete. However, I assume, You are trying to access the events from Elasticsearch to your piece of code.

You can try hitting the Elasticsearch api to fetch this json, and access the message field as well. Example below:

```
**SYNTAX**
curl -XGET "<elasticsearch_ip>:<elasticsearchport(default is 9200)>/<index_name>/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'<query to fetch the index documents>'



**EXAMPLE** 
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "query": {    "match_all": {}  }}'
```